# How do I display a ‘second power of x’ in an UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I want to display "x2" (second power of "x") in a UILabel. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I've found the answer myself and it's really simple. In IB there's the "Special characters" menu, which contains lots of characters including second power of "x". Then you just click on the label, press cmd+1 and drag'n'drop the character into the "Text" field of the Inspector window.

Answer (score 4):

There’s a Unicode character [0x00b2](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) (², superscript two) that should do the trick.